# Which is the alamofire object mapper and alamofire pod version supported for xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode7.2

i cannot compile xcode after installing this i am getting error

`pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.1.4'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.2'
   pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', ‘2.1.2’`

Comment: In transformtype i am getting undeclared object i mean this version is not supporting in xcode 7.2

Comment: Use `ObjectMapper` instead of `AlamofireObjectMapper` https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Answer (score 1):

Use Alamofire version 3.0

It will work on xcode 7.2